# How to upload firmware to 8-bit Ender-3 1.1.2 without USB port

Tags: marlin

We have an old Ender-3, and the board is numbered 1.1.2. We're trying to update the firmware, but there isn't a USB port (the previous owner seems to have desoldered the USB port?!) so we're figuring out how to do it by the ISP pins and/or SD card. Using the ISP pins on the board and an Arduino, we've successfully blanked it and put a bootloader on, but we have no idea how to put the OS (Marlin) on now. We can only find versions of Marlin as far back as 1.1.4 as well.

Apparently you can't upload the OS via SD on 8-bit printers, which the 1.1.2 is. Is there a way to do it using the ISP pins or over the SD or something? I'd rather not have to solder a surface-mount USB port to damaged pads on the motherboard without proper surface-mount facilities...

We also have 4.2.2s which I've uploaded OSs to without issue.

Comment: you can use a regular iron to surface mount a microusb header, especially one that's already been used (pre-tinned). there's only 4 traces to connect, so even if damaged, you can follow them back and vampire to another exposed pad, like 5v from the voltage regulator for example. in fact, it doesn't even need to be on the PCB; keep the bodge wires short and manually run 4 24awg wires to the various connection points on the PCB and usb connector. that should last enough to re-upload.

Comment: @dandavis we're trying to solder to the surface mount pads right now and it's very difficult to get the heat on all the pads at once. we don't have a heat gun to hand so we might need to get/borrow one...? it doesn't help that it's been used because the pads seem damaged

Comment: you don't have to get them all at once, one finger at a time works, as does copious solder. You can clean it up at the end with solder braid/wick, or just a stripped stranded copper wire, like you might use for speakers, to soak up an extra solder.

Comment: good idea; we'll have a go on monday and let you know, thanks :)

Comment: Any news? If it doesn't work, might be a good excuse to get a new/better main board. That's what i did after fixing it twice...